# Why is it if anyone asks a question, no one can ever just give the answer for the question?

Tags: discussion

If someone asks a question why do people have a hard time just giving the simple answer? There is always some alternative answer that sometimes has nothing to do with the sought after information. Even worse is when some one gets on here and answers by flat out refusing to answer...whats the point in that? I get "ask google, or try something else", or "if you don't know your not trying". Its just very frustrating when you ask simple questions and can not get simple answers. If you do not want to answer question, then do not comment. Its that simple.

Comment: To paraphrase your final sentence in a pointed way, please don't assume I'm intending this as sharply as you formulated that sentence: *If you can't read the help pages on what is on-topic, on how to ask good questions, how to use tags, don't ask. It's that simple.* This site works two ways: people get good answers, actually, all over the place, for free. But sustaining such a system of volunteer answerers requires questions to be high-quality. Otherwise, potential helpers just lose interest, and good questions get lost in a repetitive/off-topic flood of questions.

Comment: You, in this very case, asked a question that is off-topic and opinionated, and you abuse all tags (the absence of tags that describe your question would have been a hint it's off-topic here). If that is the quality of questions typically seen, then please don't be surprised the community self-moderation mechanism tends to give you negative feedback - that is intended. Both as a means of quality assurance for questions, and as a way to directly help you improve your next question. It's how this platform works! Asking for critical comments to *not* be given is against the very principle of it.

Comment: If you see comments like "just google it", please feel free to flag those as rude, or at least "no longer needed", as those types of comments are not constructive in any way. Thanks!

Comment: 1. "just ask google" and other RTFM answers are rude and should be flagged.  However extremely basic questions that the asker could easily have answered themselves with man or google or whatever are also rude (and waste the time of every reader / potential answerer rather than just a few seconds of the asker's time), and should be downvoted/closed/deleted. If it's not worth YOUR time to do some minimal attempt to figure it out, then what makes you think it's worth wasting OUR time on it?

Comment: 2. RE: "alternative answers" - sometimes the question that is being asked is fundamentally flawed in some way. Either the entire approach is wrong, or the tool they want to use is the wrong tool for the job, or it's yet another [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). And if someone asks "how do I shoot myself in the foot", it's our responsibility to say "you probably don't want to do that, do this instead". You're here asking experts for advice - you should at least consider that someone with many years of experience might know a thing or two and make an effort to understand what they're saying

Comment: 3. Answers here are written not just for the person who asked the question, but for everyone who comes after with similar questions.   If an answer doesn't explain what it's doing and why, it's a bad answer.  Cargo-cult answers (i.e. "just copy and paste this command into your terminal" are NOT good answers, they're terrible answers.

Comment: I'm guilty of "just ask google" (never as an answer, only as a comment). I do so when I type the exact title of the question into google and get answers. To me, that's NOT a good question on stackexchange as it's either a duplicate (easily searched ON stack exchange) or has answers outside of stackexchange that can be found with minimal effort

Comment: @JaromandaX the problem with that approach is that, especially with Google, search results are often extremely different for different users. For example, if I search for “wine” or “bash”, I get results mostly related to the corresponding programs; but someone who doesn’t search for Unix-related information gets results related to the grape-based beverage and the clothing brand. Thus especially for people who aren’t already familiar with Unix and Linux, searching for the answer in a search engine might not give them anything useful.

Comment: @StephenKitt - depends on your google-fu - but yeah, granted, I'll try to stop doing that (and mentioning googol, rather than *generic world wide web search engine of choice*, got into trouble for just suggesting googol once)

Comment: @JaromandaX The aim of this site is to be the site you would end up on after asking a search engine for directions, so asking users to search elsewhere for answers is counterproductive. Yes, the answer may be in a manual or in some other official documentation, but that should not prevent you from summarising it and making it relevant to the user seeking help. Note that a Unix utility's manual is a description of a tool, not an instruction on how to use the tool in any particular situation.

Comment: Nowadays there is a well known IA which does more than half the work in many situations. What would result from remember people that it exists, specially questions that are a matter of tranlate a problem from natural language to any computing language ? Also, when the answer or research was trivial, it is a good thing to teach the questioner how he could learn to use resource.

Comment: Given that the questioner here also wrote https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/42714/03-honda-accord-lx-2-4-vtech-misfires-and-stalls-when-cold#comment138718_42714, I think that we probably shouldn't be expending much of our time and effort on this.

Answer (score 5):

A few quick points from me:

> alternative answer that sometimes has nothing to do with the sought after information

A comment and/or downvote would be appropriate here. Perhaps the answerer misunderstood the question, which means other potential answerers might as well, so an edit to the question might be in order. Or, it's a simple misunderstanding on their part, and they self-delete after realizing it via a comment or downvote.

> answers by flat out refusing to answer

I assume you mean *comments* here, because otherwise it's an *Answer* and can be voted on and commented on. As I wrote initially in a comment on your question here, comments that are rude or simply non-constructive (e.g. "go google it") can be flagged as -- at least -- no longer needed, or rude/abusive as needed. Don't engage in drawn out disagreements in the comments; take the parts that are useful for improving your posts and ignore the rest (again, flagging as needed).

Separately, we're all volunteers here; if you simply don't get an answer, perhaps no one has an answer, or the one person who could answer it hasn't seen it yet, etc etc. My best suggestions are:

- be patient
- supply as much useful detail as you can that would help other people replicate your situation
- gain reputation in other ways and then attract attention to your question with a bounty